# Turn of the beep sounds on Pepper robot

Tags: pepper

The Pepper robot use beep sounds to indicate when it start and end listing to something.

This nerves a lot.

Is there a way to turn this off without decreasing the main volume?

Comment: which version of NAOqi are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erasing wavs is a bit rude :)

You can simply disable the audio feedback by using calls to the ALSpeechRecognition method nammed setAudioExpression.

```
asr = ALProxy("ALSpeechRecognition")
asr.setAudioExpression( False )
```

More info about this api can be found here:
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/audio/alspeechrecognition-api.html

Comment: Yes thats the better solution :-)

Comment: The question is how can I set this up globaly? This `False` sould have inpact when Pepper is turned on.

Comment: Put this settings at pepper's startup thru "Robots Applications" in choregraphe for instance.

Comment: @AlexandreMazel Thanks for the hint. I can create such start-up-scripts local via SSH on the robot or should I use choreograph for it. Which type of project and boxes should I use here in Choreograph?

Answer (score 1):

The files of the sounds you mention are located here:

```
/opt/aldebaran/share/naoqi/wav/begin_reco.wav
/opt/aldebaran/share/naoqi/wav/end_reco.wav
```

You could replace that file with silence, but without root access I dont think it is possible.

Comment: Yes. No root access here. Payed so much money for a machine where the factory doesn't allow me root access...